# Click button of other window from other process

Tags: c, winapi, sendmessage

I'm new to WinAPI and I already created an empty window. Now I want to make a little hack for the tutorial program of Cheat Engine. I already know, how to change values in the memory of other processes. But as soon as I changed a value in the tutorial program, I'm forced to click a "next" button. So my question is: **Is it possible to send a click command to a window of another process?** I have a handle of the window, a handle of the process and the process id (if it is not the same).

The only thing I know about the buttons is, that their text is always "next".

Here is a shortened version of my code:

```
HWND hWnd = FindWindow (NULL, L"Window's title");               // Search startup window

DWORD pid;                                                      // Get process id
GetWindowThreadProcessId (hWnd, &pid);

HANDLE hProc = OpenProcess (PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pid);    // Get access to process

DWORD base = 0x789ABCDE;                                        // Get value of static pointer
ReadProcessMemory (hProc, &base, &base, 4, NULL);

WORD offset = 0xBCDE;                                           // Write to memory
WriteProcessMemory (hProc, (void *)(base + offset), (void *)5000, 4, NULL);

// Send click command (???)
```

Sorry, if my english and/or some technical terms aren't correct, but I'm new to Win32.

---

**EDIT:**
I discovered, that the tutorial forbits every memory access, so my project will never work. In addition, `GetLastError();` always returns `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` when I try to install a second windows procedure for the tutorial program. Do I have to use `hProc` instead of `pid` in `SetWindowsHookEx (WH_CALLWNDPROC, &fnHook, NULL, pid);`?

Comment: Use spy++ to get the button id.

Comment: Why not use automation?

Comment: I don't have spy++ (VS2013 Express); Automation?

Comment: Yes automation. That's the supported way to invoke gui actions in different processes. Hard to see how hacking process memory is relevant here.

Comment: Your edit does not make much sense. You seem to be trying things at random. Again, one wonders why you won't use automation. Why are you trying to make life hard for yourself?

Answer (score 0):

The *simplest* way to do this is to use SendMessage() to send an WM_LBUTTONDOWN and then a WM_LBUTTONUP message to the given window, something like

```
// x, y are the coords
SendMessage(hWnd, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, MK_LBUTTON, MAKELPARAM(x, y));
SendMessage(hWnd, WM_LBUTTONUP, MK_LBUTTON, MAKELPARAM(x, y));
```

This may or may not work in your particular case; if the spot that you're trying to click is actually in a child window or a popup you've just "clicked" the wrong window, and a lot of apps rely on other messages.

The more reliable way to do it is to call SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE, ...), and "play" the mouse messages through the given hook procedure. I haven't done that in a couple of decades so can't really talk about it in detail.

Comment: -1 The `SendMessage` approach is brittle. If the target process hangs, so will your process. It relies on external state it cannot control. The target window could get obscured in between your two calls, causing the `WM_LBUTTONUP` to be dispatched to another window. `SendMessage` is also subject to UIPI. The window hook cannot be used to *"play"* mouse messages. It can only act as an observer. The reliable and documented solution is [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx).